# How do I remove duplicate rows in a Pandas DataFrame based on values in a specific column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes that have duplicates but I need to remove only the rows that have duplicate VIN numbers and doesn't look at the other cells.

```
0  230  5UXCR6C50KTQ4xxxx  KLL34607  2019 BMW M3                        
1  116  5UXCR4C00LLW6xxxx  LLW63494  2020 BMW X5           Not Found      
2  109  5UXCR6C06LLL7xxxx  LLL76916  2020 BMW X5         Need Detail

38  229  5UXCR6C50KLL3xxxx  MLL23650  2019 BMW X5                    
43  115  5UXCR4C00LLW6xxxx  LLW63494  2020 BMW X5                    
37  108  5UXCR6C06LLL7xxxx  LLL76916  2020 BMW X5
```

The last 2 rows look like different rows to pandas but I need to merge the two data frames and remove the rows just based on those VIN numbers and ignores the 'Not Found' and 'Need Detail'

I've tried `.drop_duplicates`   `.cumsum()`  and a few other methods but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're trying to say is that you need to concatenate the two dataframes and then remove all duplicated rows based on only a subset of columns.

You can use `pd.concat([df1, df2]).drop_duplicates(subset=['VIN'])`

where *subset* is a list of column names that are used to drop the duplicated rows.
(See the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) for extra details)